# .NET MAUI, is there a way to make a CollectionView expand, instead of being scrollable?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

In .NET MAUI, if I create a CollectionView, and populate it with a list of ~50 integers, the list is displayed in full length on Android, and on iOS it scrolls.

How can I make a CollectionView show and be as "long" as the amount of item in it, without having to scroll?
**Is the an option for setting either mode, or is it based on the OS?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the collectionview's default behavior is:

1. The Content Height > CollectvionView's Height. Such as: there are 10 items and each item's height is 50. But the CollectvionView's Height is 300. The content's height is 500 and it will scrolls.
2. The Content Height <= CollectvionView's Height. it will be displayed in full length.

And you said:

> In .NET MAUI, if I create a CollectionView, and populate it with a list of ~50 integers, the list is displayed in full length on Android, and on iOS it scrolls.

This is because different platform has different default value for the view's height. If you set item's height as 50. It will also scrolls on Android.

So if you want to make a CollectionView show and be as "long" as the amount of item in it. Just make sure the **Content Height <= CollectvionView's Height**. But I think the scrollable CollectionView is better.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the default behavior of collection view is not that simple.

However, I do not think that you need CollectionView here.

A StackLayout, with set BindableLayout.ItemSource will do the same work.
(Wrap it yourself with ScrollView, if needed)

The benefits of CollectionView, in your case (list of 50 integers) can be ignored. The performance will be about the same, if not even better.

MAUI Example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout#define-item-appearance

Comment: You could improve your answer by giving a code example.

Comment: @Julian done. Its with images, not integers. But the concept is what is important.